# JavaDB wont start on App start, giving me a java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:

Tags: java, sql, exception, derby, javadb

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException :
Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
```

I am using Netbeans.
If I go to the Services Tab and rightclick Java DB and start Server it works fine.

How can I do this programmaticly at Runtime. I just need whatever method will start the Java DB Server.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [how to use JavaDB with a desktop application](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javadb/). They describe how to start it programmatically there.

Comment: Actually there is not one answer on that page on how to start the db servers, only how to connect to them once they are created and started.

Comment: The embedded server will be started automatically as soon as you load the driver with `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");` as described on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the [NetworkServerControl](https://db.apache.org/derby/javadoc/publishedapi/jdbc4/org/apache/derby/drda/NetworkServerControl.html) additional documentation can be found [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html)

```
NetworkServerControl server = new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), port);
```

Comment: This looks like it should be the one I needed but had a little trouble implementing it.  Do you know where there may be some samples I can see to view how it is done?

Comment: Search on "embedded server"; that's the terminology that Derby use for this, I believe. For example: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/radminembeddedserverex.html

Comment: Embedded and Network Server are not the same, the network server can be accessed from anywhere the embedded database is only available in the current runtime. And I provided an additional link.